# How to add token when using axios to send an ajax request?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am using Laravel `5.3` and vue.js `2.0`，
And I use axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to send ajax requests,
I follow the docs to set the `TOKEN` like this:

```
<script>

    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;  //The error is at this line.

    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: function () {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                axios.get('/articles').then(function (response) {
                    response.data.forEach(function (item) {
                        item.selected = false;
                    });
                    this.items = response.data;
                }).catch(function (error) {

                    console.log(error);
                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

the error in console is like this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: AUTH_TOKEN is not defined
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

have you set `AUTH_TOKEN` on the window? If not `window.AUTH_TOKEN` will naturally not be defined.

A common set up in the head of a laravel app is:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

This would therefore set the csrf token. I wouldn't imagine this is how you'll be setting an Auth token so you'll probably just need to look into why you are calling `window.AUTH_TOKEN`

In terms of how you generate your token that is dependant on what type you require but once you have it you may want to look instead at [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) for storing it. Doing so will allow you access to it throughout your app, without having to store anything on the window.

Comment: I don't know much about laravel, do we need to use `JSON.parse("<?php echo ...?>")` instead of `<?php echo ...?>` ?

Comment: `echo json_encode()` will convert the php array to output a JSON object so it works fine. The issue here seems simply that `AUTH_TOKEN` is not being set anywhere. I gave that script tag more as an example of how global js vars can be set in Laravel if they require server side parsing.

Comment: Ah! I've always used the approach in my last comment and never thought the output json string is already valid javascript object literal...

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
```

and you can remove the

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

part